# How do I temporarily suppress error Messages in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

The following command attempts to reseed the identity value for all tables in the current database.

```
exec sp_MSforeachtable @command1 = 'DBCC CHECKIDENT(''?'', RESEED, 1)'
```

An error message is generated for each table that does not have an identity column.

> Msg 7997, Level 16, State 1, Line 1    'MyTable' does not contain an identity column.

**I would like to suppress all error messages for this single line of code above, but not suppress them for the rest of the code in the SQL file.**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this (untested, but I think you'll get the gist):

```
declare tbls cursor for
select object_name([object_id])
from sys.identity_columns
where objectproperty([object_id], 'IsMSShipped') = 0
declare @tbl_name sysname, @cmd nvarchar(max)
open tbls

while(1=1)
begin
   fetch next from tbls into @tbl_name
   if(@@fetch_status <> 0)
      break
   set @cmd = 'DBCC CHECKIDENT(''' + @tbl_name + ''', RESEED, 1)'
   exec(@cmd)
end
close tbls
deallocate tbls
```

Comment: Just letting you know, "with no_infomsgs" hides all but the errors. Thanks for the alternative!